# Why does JPA calls to the class name on the database instead to the one i've named in the annotation @Table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm making this program and JPA keeps pushing this sentence

```
2020-11-28 13:55:01.244  INFO 20236 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms

Hibernate: select cliente0_.customernumber as customernumber1_0_, cliente0_.contactlastname as contactlastname2_0_, cliente0_.city as city3_0_, cliente0_.postalcode as postalcode4_0_, cliente0_.addressline2 as addressline5_0_, cliente0_.addressline1 as addressline6_0_, cliente0_.employeenumber as employeenumber14_0_, cliente0_.state as state7_0_, cliente0_.creditlimit as creditlimit8_0_, cliente0_.contactfirstname as contactfirstname9_0_, cliente0_.customername as customername10_0_, cliente0_.salesrepemployeenumber as salesrepemployeen11_0_, cliente0_.country as country12_0_, cliente0_.phone as phone13_0_ from customers cliente0_

2020-11-28 13:55:03.251  WARN 20236 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000

2020-11-28 13:55:03.251 ERROR 20236 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00904: "CLIENTE0_"."EMPLOYEENUMBER": invalid identifier

2020-11-28 13:55:03.264 ERROR 20236 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "CLIENTE0_"."EMPLOYEENUMBER": invalid identifier
```

It calls for Cliente0_, even when i've named it "CUSTOMERS" on the @Table(name = "CUSTOMERS") annotation.

```
package cl.Claudio.java.entidades;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cliente {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMERNUMBER")
    private Integer numeroDeCliente;
```

I'm kind of desperate. Can i have a hand on this?

Comment: `CUSTOMERNUMBER` for `numeroDeCliente` and select has `EMPLOYEENUMBER`? Is there some code missing in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking a table name for an alias (check the `from` clause: `from customers cliente0_`)

```sql
select cliente0_.customernumber as customernumber1_0_,
 cliente0_.contactlastname as contactlastname2_0_,
 cliente0_.city as city3_0_,
 cliente0_.postalcode as postalcode4_0_,
 cliente0_.addressline2 as addressline5_0_,
 cliente0_.addressline1 as addressline6_0_,
 cliente0_.employeenumber as employeenumber14_0_,
 cliente0_.state as state7_0_,
 cliente0_.creditlimit as creditlimit8_0_,
 cliente0_.contactfirstname as contactfirstname9_0_,
 cliente0_.customername as customername10_0_,
 cliente0_.salesrepemployeenumber as salesrepemployeen11_0_,
 cliente0_.country as country12_0_,
 cliente0_.phone as phone13_0_ 
from customers cliente0_
```

Hibernate create aliases for pretty much every table and column.

**[edit]** let me clear my answer: you are asking the wrong question. If your problem is about the error *oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "CLIENTE0_"."EMPLOYEENUMBER": invalid identifier* which mean you have one of those:

- A mapping error
- A table not up to date with the mapping
- You are pointing to the wrong database (it may seem stupid, but I think that it happens :))
- The compiled entities that Hibernate reference are not up to date with the code you are using.

This may help you in finding the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @ClaudioRowe: yes, the error seems to be with "employeenumber" field. Are you sure it exists and contains no typo?

Comment: I guess it is another thing, i need to put the annotations and references right. Thanks for the help!